# Error: Object Required: '[undefined]' for a dictionary object

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

***Requirement:***

Please read the following template:

```
PID     Status      LPID

10       Closed      25
11       Open        25
31       Open        31
25       Closed      25
54       Open        31
17       Open        17
20       Closed      31
88       closed      77
77       closed      77
101      Closed      66
102      closed      220
```

Now when PID!= LPID, that PID is defined as CPID(Child Process ID),Otherwise it is a PPID(Parent process ID)

**Update** There can be some entries say 101 and 102,which are child ,but their Parents don't have a thier own etires thus 66,220 shouldn't come to the output result as `66 Parent` and `220 Parent` no such output should be there.

Now I am looking for a code which will tell which is parent and Which is child- means marking them in another sheet.At the Same time i want to list down all CPID,with PPID in the same row,If any PPID has child Processes themselves. Output would be look like below

```
PID   Type Of Process?    Child1   Child1   Child3 .... ChildN
10       Child
11       Child
31       Parent             54      20
25       Parent             10      11
54       Child
17       Parent
20       Child
88       Child
77       Parent             88
```

I have written a code using VBScript,but with the actual sheet it is too slow. For 2500 data it is taking close to 1 hour.So I Want a more faster process than my one.

I wrote the below code to meet some requirement: But getting an error which is not understandable.

Can you help me here? I tried in both way the syntax `Add` or `=`- nothing helped.

Option Explicit

```
Class cP
 Public m_sRel
 Public m_dicC
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
     m_sRel     = "Child"
     Set m_dicC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End Sub
    Public Function show()
     show = m_sRel & " " & Join(m_dicC.Keys)
    End Function
End Class

Dim objSheet1,objSheet2,TotalRows,TotalcolCopy,strPathExcel1
Dim oXls  : Set oXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim dicP  : Set dicP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim nRow,nP

strPathExcel1 = "D:\Finalscripts\test.xlsx"
oXls.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1
'oXls.Workbooks.Open(oFs.GetAbsolutePathName("Test.xlsx"))
Set objSheet1 = oXls.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("A")
Set objSheet2 = oXls.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("B")


TotalRows=oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(objSheet1.Columns(1)) - 3
TotalcolCopy=oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("ABC", objSheet1.Rows(3), 0)

objSheet1.Range(objSheet1.Cells(4,1),objSheet1.Cells(TotalRows,TotalcolCopy)).Copy(objSheet2.Range("A1"))
objSheet2.Range(objSheet2.Cells(1,2),objSheet2.Cells(TotalRows,TotalcolCopy-1)).Delete(-4159)
'Dim aData : aData=objSheet2.Cells.SpecialCells(12)'xlCellTypeVisible
TotalRows = oXls.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(objSheet2.Columns(1))
Dim aData : aData = objSheet2.Range("A1:B"&TotalRows)

'MsgBox(LBound(aData, 1)&"And"&UBound(aData, 1))

   For nRow = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)

     Set dicP(aData(nRow, 1)) = New cP

   Next

   For nRow = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)

        If aData(nRow, 1) = aData(nRow, 2) Then
           dicP(aData(nRow, 1)).m_sRel = "Parent"
        Else
           dicP(aData(nRow, 2)).m_dicC.Add   aData(nRow, 1), 0         '(aData(nRow, 1)) = 0
        End If

   Next

    objSheet2.Cells.ClearContents'To clear all the previous contenets of the sheet#2

    nRow=1
    For Each nP In dicP.Keys()

    objSheet2.Cells(nRow,1).Value=nP
    objSheet2.Cells(nRow,2).Value=dicP(nP).m_sRel

       'WScript.Echo nP, dicP(nP).show()


    nRow=nRow+1  
    Next
```

*Error:* Object Required: '[undefined]' at the line `dicP(aData(nRow, 2)).m_dicC.Add   aData(nRow, 1), 0         '(aData(nRow, 1)) = 0`

**EDIT:** To get the child list,I wrote the below code with the above:

```
       For Each nP In dicP.Keys()

    objSheet2.Cells(nRow,1).Value=nP
    objSheet2.Cells(nRow,2).Value=dicP(nP).m_sRel
    objSheet2.Range("C"&nRow).Value=dicP(nP).m_dicC.Keys

       'WScript.Echo nP, dicP(nP).show()


    nRow=nRow+1  
       Next
```

But Desired output is not coming,Can you suggest here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't blame you for not being able to find the problem. Your code is difficult to read, debug, or figure out what you're intending to do.

That being said, the problem is that `dicP(aData(nRow,2))` has not been defined and therefore you cannot access the `m_dicC` property because it returns an empty variant instead of an object. When you attempt to call the property, you receive the error message that you indicated.

You can also replicate the error with a much simpler script:

```
Dim dicP: Set dicP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dicP("test").JumpUpJumpUpAndGetDown 'Silly I know.
```

Since there's no corresponding object, the code has no idea what to do with the method call I passed and indicates that an Object is Required.

My guess is that you either intended to do this:

```
 For nRow = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
     Set dicP(aData(nRow, 1)) = New cP
     'Also add a cP for the nRow, 2
     Set dicP(aData(nRow, 2)) = New cP
   Next
```

Or this:

`dicP(aData(nRow, 1)).m_dicC.Add   aData(nRow, 1), 0` note `(nrow, 1)` instead of `(nrow, 2)`

I would suggest at least adding comments to your code because even if you're the one maintaining it in the future, it seems overly complex and is hard to grasp what it is doing. You'll probably forget how it works and will need to spend awhile (like I did) figuring out what is going on.

Comment: please see my updated description for which the code was developed. please help me or let me know if you have confusion for the same.

Comment: the child lists are in the columns, i didn't show them in the description!!

Comment: I cannot tell how your response has relevance to anything I posted. Did you read my answer?

Comment: Sorry! Yes i have seen,just to make the code background more clear,means why i developed it,posted the requirement description also!

Comment: the only problem I was facing still,I couldn't figure out that how I will put the child ID in the contiguous column? That's not coming in my head :-) Can you help me here if possible?