# Can we assign the dictionary keys to a column with a single statement?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have large dictionary keys,Which I want to insert to a column of an excel sheet.Which I have done by the below :

```
Dim a, d, i 'Create some variables
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "a", "Athens" 'Add some keys and items.
d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
d.Add "c", "Cairo"

a = d.keys 'Get the keys

For i = 0 To d.Count - 1 'Iterate the array
    ob.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = a(i)
Next
```

But can it be done in one statement? say `obj2.Cells(1,1).Resize(dicP.Count,1)=a` I tried this one also but it is putting only the first key in the range I defined by `Resize`.

Comment: you may also use a loop to populate your `dictionary` instead of adding one by one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
Sub a()
    Dim d '<~~ Create some variable
    Dim sKeys()

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add "a", "Athens" 'Add some keys and items.
    d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
    d.Add "c", "Cairo"

    '~~> Get dictionary Keys
    sKeys = d.keys

    Range("A1").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(sKeys)
End Sub
```

Comment: Will then the column be filled with the all Key values of that Dic object?

Comment: in my case specified column contains only the `sKeys(0)` values,not getting the whole contents of the array to the column?

Comment: I just tested it and it works... Can you update the code that you are using?

Comment: can you help me in the below post? I wrote it but not getting the expected output as I described in the description. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975082/error-object-required-undefined-for-a-dictionary-object/13977150#comment19287151_13977150

Comment: @DanielCook is already helping you with that problem. I would recommend that you be patient and let him help you out ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity Is there any way to put the column values direct to the dictionary Key list,just the reverse what we did here?